# Setting Link Attribute to an element not working and can't figure out why

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set a link attribute to a field of a table, I think I am following the right steps, but I am missing something.

I have this function that creates a table out of VAR data .
And What I wanted is to to transform the "first_name" field into a link (taken from the 'url' field of the object)

```js
function createTable(data, field) {
    var tbody = document.getElementById("senate-data")
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var row = document.createElement("tr");
     
        var cell1 = document.createElement("td");
        var cell2 = document.createElement("td");
        var cell3 = document.createElement("td");
        var cell4 = document.createElement("td");
        var cell5 = document.createElement("td");
        var nameLink = document.createElement('a'); //created this var to later set the atrribute
        
        
        cell1.innerHTML = data[i].first_name;
        cell2.innerHTML = data[i].party;
        cell3.innerHTML = data[i].state;
        cell4.innerHTML = data[i].seniority;
        cell5.innerHTML = data[i].votes_with_party_pct;
        
        nameLink.setAttribute('href', data[i].url);
        cell1.appendChild(nameLink);//here i try to apend the var which is already a link, to the 'td' element ,getting the name turned into a link
        
        
        row.appendChild(cell1);
        row.appendChild(cell2);
        row.appendChild(cell3);
        row.appendChild(cell4);
        row.appendChild(cell5);
        
        tbody.appendChild(row);;

        }
    }

createTable(data.results[0].members,
  ["first_name", "party", "state", "seniority", "votes_with_party_pct"]
);
```

It is not working, and I don't know if it is just a small detail i am missing, or what I am trying is completely wrong.

pd: i am begging with javascript, so If my method is not right, i would be looking for something easy for my level...

Comment: You have to put innerText ( or append a createTextNode() ) inside the hyperlinks as well if you want to be able to click them. The href attribute only states the hyperlink that will be opened, not the actual text the link will show.

Comment: Replace `cell1.innerHTML = data[i].first_name;` with `nameLink.innerHTML = data[i].first_name;`

Comment: @ChrisG it worked! ...can't believe it was that easy ... Would you care to explain the logic behind??  Maybe I am still to square minded, but I thought i had to populate de "cell1" first (like it was) and then connect it with the new created variable "nameLink"

Comment: @notADevYet The syntax for `<a>` tag is : `<a href="source"> Link Text to Display </a>`. In your earlier code, you had the first_name inside `<td>` but not inside`<a>`. The output of your earlier code would be `<td>First Name<a href="source"></a>`. Nothing inside the '`<a>` to display. The link was there but you couldn't see it. First Name was outside the `<a>` and hence it was just normal text.`nameLink.innerHTML` adds contents inside the `<a>`. But `cell1.innerHTML` adds contents inside `<td>` not`<a>`

Comment: You set the name as content for the first cell. Then you appended an empty link tag. You did set its `href`, but the link didn't have any text so had a width of zero. You say you thought the cell had to be populated first, but putting just the name into the cell isn't what you want. The final result should be `<td><a href="...">name</a></td>` so you have to 1. set the link as contents for the cell 2. set the name as contents for the link (the order doesn't matter)

Comment: @AmalK golden ...thanks for adapting the explanation to my level.

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks to you too. Sounds clearer put that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, you have to add actual text to the hyperlink for it to be clickable. The href attribute only specifies the url to visit on click, not the text that will be shown as the hyperlink.

```js
var data = {
  results: [
    {
      members: [
        { first_name: 'John', party: 'Dems', state: 'AZ', seniority: 1, votes_with_party_pct: 37, url: '#john' },
        { first_name: 'Jane', party: 'Reps', state: 'TX', seniority: 1, votes_with_party_pct: 15, url: '#jane' },
        { first_name: 'Bob', party: 'Greens', state: 'CA', seniority: 2, votes_with_party_pct: 38, url: '#bob'},
        { first_name: 'Alice', party: 'Indeps', state: 'NY', seniority: 3, votes_with_party_pct: 14, url: '#alice' }
      ]
    }
  ]
};


function createTable(data, field) {
    var tbody = document.getElementById("senate-data")
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var row = document.createElement("tr");
     
        var cell1 = document.createElement("td");
        var cell2 = document.createElement("td");
        var cell3 = document.createElement("td");
        var cell4 = document.createElement("td");
        var cell5 = document.createElement("td");
        var nameLink = document.createElement('a'); //created this var to later set the atrribute
        
        // Add the name to the hyperlink instead.
        nameLink.appendChild( document.createTextNode( data[i].first_name ));
        nameLink.setAttribute('href', data[i].url);
        
        // Append the hyperlink to the cell. The name is now clickable as a hyperlink.
        cell1.appendChild(nameLink);
        cell2.innerHTML = data[i].party;
        cell3.innerHTML = data[i].state;
        cell4.innerHTML = data[i].seniority;
        cell5.innerHTML = data[i].votes_with_party_pct;
        
        row.appendChild(cell1);
        row.appendChild(cell2);
        row.appendChild(cell3);
        row.appendChild(cell4);
        row.appendChild(cell5);
        
        tbody.appendChild(row);;

        }
    }

createTable(data.results[0].members,
  ["first_name", "party", "state", "seniority", "votes_with_party_pct"]
);
```

```html
<table id="senate-data"></table>
```

PS: You're not using your `field` array. I guess the intention is to loop over it instead to create the table so you do not have to change the createTable function if a field name disappears, changes name, or is added.

Comment: it works great too....amazing how many ways to do the same thing there are.
buff...but I feel too far away from being able to do it by my own ...
Not sure If i am ever going to get any real skills  XD ...

Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: There's subtle differences and one way may be easier sometimes. For example, you have to add a text node between two existing sibling nodes. 1) If you do that with `.createElement()`, you have longer code since you have to:create element, set text on element, select parent node of the siblings, `.insertAfter()` on the parent node referring the sibling node. 2) If you try the same with `.innerHTML = '';`, you have to find the exact position of the sibling inside the HTML string, which can be more difficult that selecting and append. But that can be written in one line of code.

Comment: I think I am getting it ...long way to go still  (for me)
Thanks again!